# Elementary row operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find the reduced row echelon form of the then: M =
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & -1 \\
> 1 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation} and describe in detail the elementary row operations that you use

M = 
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
* & * \\
* & *
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
? & ? \\
? & ?
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
y & y \\
y & y
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
? & ? \\
? & ?
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x & x \\
x & x
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I've learned that you have to have a star matrix times original matrix equals ? matrix

and then ? matrix moves down to where original matrix was at. but I don't know how to determine neither * and ? matrix from the beginning. If I find out how to calculate ? and * matrices and I know I can find rest of matrices easily!! Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Subtracting $\DeclareMathOperator{Row}{Row}\Row_1$ from $\Row_2$ gives
$$
E_1A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $E_1$ is the elementary matrix
$$
E_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Multiplying $\Row_2$ by $1/2$ gives
$$
E_2E_1A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $E_2$ is the elementary matrix 
$$
E_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Finally, adding $\Row_2$ to $\Row_1$ gives
$$
E_3E_2E_1A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $E_3$ is the elementary matrix
$$
E_3=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
This shows that the reduced row-echelon form of $A$ is 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$